# Int Main (using classes) not returning a calculated variable

Tags: c++, class, friend, return-type

We are learning about classes in my C++ class and for a homework assignment we have to create a sphere class that will calculate the surface area and volume. I am playing around with the volume function trying to get it to return the value for `V` after calculation. I am reading some stuff around Google that the `return` statement ends the function and returns whatever you wrote after it, but it is not doing that for me. What am I not seeing here??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class sphere
{
    private:
        double r;

    public:
        double sarea();
        double volume();
        void Input();
        sphere();
        double GetRad();


};

double ReadPositiveDouble(string prompt)
{
    double r=0.0;
    double rad=0.0;

    cout<<prompt<<endl;
    cin>>r;
    if(r>=0.0)
    {
        rad=r;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr<<"Cannot set radius to negative.\n";
    }   
    return r;
}

void sphere::Input()
{
    double rad=0.0;

    rad=ReadPositiveDouble("Radius?");
}

double sphere::GetRad()
{
    double rad=0.0;

    return rad;
}

sphere::sphere()
{
    double radius=0.0;
}

double sphere::sarea()
{
    double rad=0.0;

    return 4*M_PI*pow(rad, 2.0);
}


double sphere::volume()
{
    double rad=0.0;
    double V=0.0;

    GetRad();
    V=(4*M_PI*pow(rad,3.0))/3;

    return V;
}



int main()
{

    double r=0.0; 


    sphere(red);
    red.Input();

    //red.sarea();
    red.volume();




    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And did you fix these error messages? Namely _"semicolon missing after declaration of class sphere"_? What's so hard about digging this one actually?

Comment: Oh man Im sorry, I'm new to C++. I was putting it after "sphere" and it wasn't working, so I undid it to see if someone could help.

Comment: @heyheythere The down-votes are there because this type of question is a very easy beginner question that gets asked a lot. Hence it should have been relatively easy to copy/paste the error into google and see if others have had the same problem, which they have. The very first two google results after searching for _semicolon missing after declaration_ answer exactly what you are asking...

Answer (score 1):

This one is a simple typo - `class` definitions must have a semicolon at the end.

```
class sphere
{
    ...
};
 ^ this is required
```

Comment: We should have a compiler to pass in compiler error messages, that explains what these compiler error messages are about. No, wait ...

Comment: Thanks Greg!! I'm new to this stuff! :/

Comment: @heyheythere: Welcome. Note that the compiler already tried to tell you what was wrong, with the message "semicolon missing after declaration of class sphere". Compiler error messages are sometimes misleading, but that one is pretty straightforward!

Comment: Yea I saw that but I tried putting after "class sphere" like this: `class sphere;` and I was just making it worse so I decided to ask here. Thanks again!